# Is there a way to marshal different struct type to same json field when not empty?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a struct for response defined in common package like this.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    Id string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    //All other int/string fields

    NestedObj *Nested `json:"nested,omitempty"`
}

type Nested struct {
    //Field causing the issue.
    ExtendedString string `json:"extended,omitempty"` //some user will need/expect a string

    //Other user need extended json field as a different object
    Extended *Extended `json:"extended,omitempty"` //changing json:extended to other json:extended1 will work as expected
                                                    //But need to have the same field name containing object or just a string field
}

type Extended struct {
    OtherField string `json:"another,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    response := &Response{Id: "UNIQUE_ID"}

    response.NestedObj = &Nested{}

    //Part 1
    response.NestedObj.ExtendedString = "value"

    b, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    //Part 1 end

    
    response1 := &Response{Id: "UNIQUE_ID"}

    response1.NestedObj = &Nested{}

    //Part 2
    response1.NestedObj.Extended = &Extended{}

    response1.NestedObj.Extended.OtherField = "value"

    b1, err := json.Marshal(response1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b1))
    //Part 2 end
    
    //Either Part 1 or 2 will be set for user type as per preference/flag/condition. 

}
```

Now as I have use pointer in struct to not export any empty field/object in json, I want to behave it like
when I set `ExtendedString` to some string value and omit the `Extended` custom struct my json should look like

```
{"id":"UNIQUE_ID",...other json fields..., "nested":{"extended": "value"}}
```

But when I set `Extended`  struct ignoring `ExtendedString` I should get the json as

```
{"id":"UNIQUE_ID",...other json fields..., "nested":{"extended": {"another":"value"}}}
```

It is sure that either one of them will be needed in marshaled json based on user preference(`if` or `switch` condition may be) as they have to have the field name as `extended` which can either be a string or json object containg other fields.

Is it possible to achieve this without duplicating the main struct?

Comment: Edit the question to show the Go code that produced the output.  Are you asking how to make ExtendedString marshal to a JSON string instead of a JSON object?

Comment: Edited the question to include a sample code. I need to have a field in json which can either be string or another object containing other json fields based on the condition of user in some flag.

Comment: @user3677365 You can always write a custom `MarshalJSON` method for `Response`.

Comment: Declare field Nested.Extended as type `interface{}`.  Set field to `string` value or `*Extended` as needed.

Comment: `interface{}` worked for now, will have to look in realtime, but does it will have any impact on cpu/memory when on high load on the server? Also what the impact of writing a custom `MarshalJSON`to achieve the same result?

Comment: @user3677365 The performance impact of using `interface{}` is nil.  A custom marshaller will not have better performance.

Comment: Thanks, using `interface{}` hoping it doesn't cause any concurrent read/write error like it happens with `map interface{}`. Will post the complete code after completing this in production in coming days.

Comment: @CeriseLimón A custom marshaller will however have the upside that you don't need to type-check and cast the value every time you need to use it in some other context. Which is code bloat and costs performance.

Comment: @super If the OP's goal is to marshal values to a JSON response, then the application only sets values to the field. There's no need for type assertions.  The custom marshaler is the approach that adds bloat.

Comment: @CeriseLimón there is certainly potential for a `MarshalJSON` to have better performance because it is able to make assumptions about the data that the generic marshaler cannot. This may eliminate code paths and/or reduce use of reflection, both of which would improve performance.

Comment: @CeriseLimón You're absolutely right. The question does however not tell us if that's the case or not. You seem to be confusing the highligting of different approaches and their pros/cons with some kind of argument for which approach is better... ?

Comment: @Adrian The interface encoder uses a sync.Map lookup to find the encoder for the concrete value.  The marshaler encoder checks the validity of the returned JSON.  I doubt that the map lookup is significantly slower than the validity check.  Both encoders use reflect values.  In the case of @super's anwer the `MarshalJSON` function executes the generic code path through the method's calls to `json.Marshal`.

Answer (score 2):

`json.Marshal` will call your type `MarshalJSON` method if one exists. Using that you can check your conditions and then return JSON that fits accordingly.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type ExtendedObj struct {
    Value string `json:"another"`
}

type Extended struct {
    str string
    Obj ExtendedObj `json:"extended"`
}

func (e* Extended) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if e.str != "" {
        return json.Marshal(struct {
            Value string `json:"extended"`
        }{e.str})
    }
    
    return json.Marshal(e)
}

func main() {
    v1 := Extended{"Hey!", ExtendedObj{}}
    jsonBytes, err := json.Marshal(&v1)
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(string(jsonBytes))
    
    v2 := Extended{"", ExtendedObj{"Hey!"}}
    jsonBytes2, err := json.Marshal(v2)
    
    fmt.Println(string(jsonBytes2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using the type to generate a JSON document, then declare the field `Nested.Extended` as type `interface{}`. Set field to a `string` or `*Extended` as needed.

The performance impact of using an `interface{}` is nil compared to other approaches such as using a [`json.Marshaler`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler).

A con of this approach is that the application must use type assertions when accessing the value in the field. If the application does read then field, then `json.Marshaler` approach shown in another answer is the better approach.

Comment: After I marshal the the struct to json it will be sent as json response. So I don't see If I need to read the value as well. Anyway though I am going to go through the @super answer as well and try to benchmark it for better performance in both the approaches.

Comment: The code in the @super answer executes all of the code used to marshal  an `interface{}` field and more. That said, the time for both approaches is negligible compared to handling a request.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached to one solution suggested by @CeriseLimón

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    Id string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    //All other int/string fields

    NestedObj *Nested `json:"nested,omitempty"`
}

type Nested struct {
    Ext interface{} `json:"extended,omitempty"`

    //Field causing the issue.
    ExtendedString string `json:"-"` //some user will need/expect a string

    //Other user need extended json field as a different object
    Extended *Extended `json:"-"` //changing json:extended to other json:extended1 will work as expected
                                //But need to have the same field name containing object or just a string field
}

type Extended struct {
    OtherField string `json:"another,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    response := &Response{Id: "UNIQUE_ID"}

    response.NestedObj = &Nested{}

    //Part 1
    response.NestedObj.Ext = "value"

    b, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b))


    //Part 1 end

    //Part 2
    extended := &Extended{}

    extended.OtherField = "value"
    //response.NestedObj = &Nested{}
    response.NestedObj.Ext = extended

    b1, err := json.Marshal(response)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(b1))
    //Part 2 end

    //Either Part 1 or 2 will be set for user type as per preference/flag/condition.

}
```

Output:

```
{"id":"UNIQUE_ID","nested":{"extended":"value"}}
{"id":"UNIQUE_ID","nested":{"extended":{"another":"value"}}}
```